# Activity representation in UML class diagram

Tags: java, android, android-activity, uml, class-diagram

I'm not sure about what I have to put in the **UML diagram representation** of my activities.

I have a login activity. So I have an `xml` file with its labels, buttons etc.
In the `LoginActivity.java` file I have some variables like `Button`, `CheckBox` etc used to add listeners.

Now I'd like to know if I have to add them in my `UML` class. Do I have to add `loginBn:Button` or `myCheckBox:CheckBox` in my `LoginActivity` representation in `UML`?

Comment: please specify what you want to accomplish with your uml diagram.

Comment: As @KaiLeßmeister said: you must b clear about your goals. Who will read your CD/AD?

Answer (score 1):

In order to answer your second question.
onStart() or onStop() with some other functions are functions getting called during thr lifetime of your activity. You dont have to write them your self. But you can initialize your activity in them or do something else.
In order to do this you have to override the funtion you wanna add your code to and first call the same method of the super class and then add your additional implementation.
For example to add your initialization to onStart you do this:

```
@Override 
public void onStart(){
     super.onStart();
     System.out.println(„my impl.“);
}
```

Normally you would initialize your buttons in there or do the setup for the activity.
For more information on the lifecycle read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have no problems about java implementation, my doubts are only about it's representation in a class diagram... So i don't need to write them in my cd... what about Buttons etc? Do i have to write them as activity's attributes? (always regarding the class diagram)

Comment: @spx305 in general i would say yes. They are part of your activity as everything else. You also could place a button in your activity without specify it in the xml tree. So placing it in your uml will ensure you got everything someone else can use when working with your software.

Comment: Thank you  for your help ;)